# extjs propertygrid grouping

Tags: grid, extjs4

I have a question about the EXTJS property Grid.

I want to display some property in this type of grid.

But i want to display theses data like a tree.

Example of data :

```
Property Group 1
----------------
    Param 1   :  Value 1
    Param 2   :  Value 2
    Param 3   :  Value 3
    Param 4   :  Value 4

Property Group 2
----------------
    Param 5   :  Value 5
    Param 6   :  Value 6
    Param 7   :  Value 7
    Param 8   :  Value 8
```

I want to display theses like a Grouping grid
like this [Grid example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/property.html), but each property group must be display in the property grid like this [Grouping Grid example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/remote-group-summary-grid.html).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Well :) Question is clear - not clear is exactly what he tried and where he stuck...

Comment: i need help for undertand how it's possible to combine the two samples, just for create a property grid with header for separate the groups. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try google to search for "extjs Extended PropertyGrid"
and here are links that I've found simuli.free.fr and [Extended Property grid](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?29152-Ext.ended-Property-Grid/page3), [Improved PropertyGrid](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?41390-Improved-PropertyGrid/page2)